# This is already the level of my speaking skills BEFORE I GOT TO

Tags: tense

Let's say you **went** to an English-speaking country, such as in the U.S.A. for work. **You** are born and raised in a **non-English speaking nation** for example in an asian country. And then, **after several years**, you've decided to **visit** your **home country,** and your friend just gave a comment on your native-sounding English speaking skills, where in fact **you already had** that BEFORE going to the U.S.A. So, making your reaction into a sentence, it goes like:

> This is already the level of my speaking skills **before I got there in the U.S.A.** for work.

The bold letters are(above), I think, a bit off. Because I'm not sure what **verb tenses** should I use here in this particular situation. Another alternative is:

> I've already **had** this level of speaking skills **before** I got there in the U.K. for work. (I'm more confident on this to be correct.)

Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making it a little more complicated than it needs to be. These sentences are perfectly understandable:

> I already had this level of speaking skill before I even got to the U.S.
>
> I already spoke this level of English before I went to live in the U.S.

Because you use ***already*** and ***before***, it is very clear that the speaking of a certain level of English happened before moving to the United States. Therefore, it's fine just to use the past tense in both.

However, if you really want to use different tenses, you can use the *past-perfect* tense in the first expression and the *perfect* tense in the second.

> I ***had spoken*** this level of English before I even ***arrived*** in the U.S.

You can also use *past perfect progressive*, because ***speaking*** was an action that occurred over a period of time:

> I ***had been speaking*** this level of English before I even ***arrived*** in the U.S.

Finally, it is acceptable to use *past perfect progressive* with *past perfect*:

> I ***had been speaking*** this level of English before I ***had arrived*** in the US.

Comment: Thx, anyway, the key thing here is that it's a good decision I've posted this question, as there are many ways to say what I am trying to say.

Comment: Oh, one thing, I believe your "U.S." is incorrect. U.S. is an adjective, whereas U.S.A is the country

Comment: Hi John, you're welcome. Most people in the U.S.A. call it just "U.S." This might be different in other parts of the world.

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/e/is-usa-a-noun/